# TypeError with VideoCapture Crop

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video-streaming, crop

I have been trying to crop a video frame using numpy slicing, as suggested by other answers to how to crop a video via OpenCV. I set up my live video capture as follows:

```py
vs = VideoCapture(1)
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,100)
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,100)
```

I then create a while loop to loop over the frames from the video stream:

```py
while True:
   frame = vs.read()
   cropped = frame[160:450, 170:470]
```

When I run the script, however, an error is returned that states:

> cropped = frame[160:450, 170:470]
>
> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called the [`cv2.VideoCapture.read()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv2.VideoCapture.read) function incorrectly. The function returns a tuple `(ret_val, frame)`. You are saving that tuple as the `frame` variable. You are getting an error because you are trying to splice that tuple. You can confirm this by using `print(type(frame))`.

If you change the line to `ret_val, frame = vs.read()` the function works as you intend and the image is correctly spliced